# How can we generate non-Gaussian random noise in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, noise

I have to add non-Gaussian random noise in synthetic seismic data in my project, but apparently I can only find the methods to add Gaussian noise as below:

```
    import numpy as np
    noise = np.random.normal(0,1,100)
```

Are there any ways to generate them?

Comment: Couldn't you use `np.random.rand()` to produce a uniform distribution? From there, you could shift to your scale and shape them according to any distribution you need.

Comment: @thomi can you please show me the example because i am a newbie. :'(